# about .net div class style

Tags: asp.net, css

My CSS file contain like this

```
#a1
{
  background_Color:"black"
}
```

In my code behind of .aspx am coded like this?

```
<div id="a1">
<asp:gridview id="gridview1" runat="server"/>
</div>
```

Now in my aspx.cs ,buuton click event i called this div class style look like this.

```
div.styles.add(a1)
```

But it doesn't show an div style in button click event? pls help me to add this div class style to button click event in asp.net?

Answer (score 1):

The CSS property name is wrong: it should be: `#a1 { background-color: black; }`

example here: http://jsfiddle.net/h6fGa/

Answer (score 0):

If you add the CSS stylesheet to the head tag of the page, the `#a1` styles will automatically be added:

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="myCSSfile.css" type="text/css" />
```

If your style isn't working, its because you have quote marks around "black". These should be removed:

```
#a1
{
    background-color:Black;
}
```

---

If you only want the black background to appear after a button click, you should change your style to be of a class, not element ID:

```
.a1
{
    background-color:Black;
}
```

Also run the div server side:

```
<div id="a1" runat="server">
```

Then add a class attribute to the element server side:

```
a1.Attributes("class") = "a1"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can refer the following link for clarification

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click.aspx